# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when summing a list of integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to sum up a list of numbers from the list but for some reason it just kept showing TypeError, can somebody tell me why and how I can fix it?

```
portfolio = [('AAPL',5, 140),('FB',3, 330)]

for i in portfolio:
    sum_value = 0
    stocks  = list (i)
    item_value = stocks[1] * stocks[2]
    print(sum(item_value))



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-5825164afaac> in <module>
      5     stocks  = list (i)
      6     item_value = stocks[1] * stocks[2]
----> 7     print(sum(item_value))
      8 
      9 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `item_value` is an integer, you can not use the `sum()` function on only one integer. Could you show the expected output?

Comment: `item_value` contains the result of  `stocks[1] * stocks[2]`. So it's just an integer.

Comment: The expected output for the codes should be like this, [in]: portfolio_value([('AAPL',5, 140),('FB',3, 330)])
[out]: 1690

Comment: The expected output for the codes should be: when the function takes inputs for both portfolios, the output should be the sum of each portfolio value, for AAPL, it would be 700, FB would be 990 and the expected output would be sum of both numbers which is 1690

Answer (score 2):

`sum` expects a iterable object, like a `list`, while you are passing just a single value.

you can solve this with:

```
sum_value = 0
for i in portfolio:
    stocks  = list (i) #if i is a tuple there is no need for this conversion
    sum_value += stocks[1] * stocks[2]
print(sum_value)
```

or in a single line:

```
sum([item[1]*item[2] for item in portfolio])
```

Comment: Tuples are indexed, so they can be accessed similar to lists. So there is no need to convert it into list `for stocks in portfolio:
    sum_value += stocks[1] * stocks[2]` this should make this even simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator expressions and pattern matching on tuples to simplify the code

```
print(sum(item_value*stock_value for (_,item_value,stock_value) in portfolio))
```

Comment: @Sayse that's generator expression and pattern matching on tuples. You're right!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
portfolio = [('AAPL', 5, 140), ('FB', 3, 330)]

item_sum = 0

for i in portfolio:
    sum_value = 0
    stocks = list(i)
    item_value = stocks[1] * stocks[2]
    item_sum += item_value
print(item_sum)
```

In your code, item_value is an int but not a list, it can't be in sum()
What you need to do is declare a variable to save and add value to it.

Comment: I tried this method but it only returned the sum of each single stock (700 and 990), they still wouldn't add up tot he sum.

Answer (score -1):

the error is because you are passing a int value into the function sum you must pass a list like this

```
sum([3,4])
```

and the result is 7

you should use something like this

```
portfolio = [('AAPL',5, 140),('FB',3, 330)]

for i in portfolio:
    sum_value = 0
    stocks  = list (i)
    item_value = stocks[1] * stocks[2]
    print(sum([sum_value,item_value]))
```